# It's a bug on Chrome, Google Maps API or what?

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome

I make this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/andycds/vds8f/1/

It places many layers over a map, using Google Maps API. I call

```
addLayer()
```

several times, with the same layer, just to be concise.

If you resize de edges of the map, making it bigger, parts of the screen disappear (only in Chrome).

It's a bug on Chrome, Google Maps API or in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this a bug in the Chrome with the  jsfiddle, when the browser try to render the map.

try to delimit the area of ​​the map

```css
    html {
        height: 200px;
    }
    body {
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #wrapper {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        background: #77C;
        color: #FFF;
        padding-left: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
    }

    #map_canvas {
        height: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, when the div is very small the screen does not disappear. But I need a full-screen map.

Comment: have you try out of  jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

All embedded google maps render strange for me in chrome.  I've even done a fresh install of chrome.  Can you got to this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics
and see if the maps there render correctly.  If not you know it's the browser and not your map code.